# Display MongoDB Documents data on a Webpage using Python Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I wrote a code using Python and trying to display all the Documents from Mongodb on a web page. However, on webpage I see the Column names, but no data.
And on the command, it does print all the data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import werkzeug
from flask_table import Table,Col
from bson.json_util import dumps
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

try:
 client = pymongo.MongoClient("XXXX")
 print("Connected to Avengers MongoClient Successfully from Project 
 Script!!!")
except:
 print("Connection to MongoClient Failed!!!")

db = client.avengers_hack_db

@app.route('/')
def Results():
    try:
        Project_List_Col = db.ppm_master_db_collection.find()#.limit(10)
        for row in Project_List_Col:
        print(row)
        return render_template('Results.html',tasks=row)

    except Exception as e:
    return dumps({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   app.run(debug = True)
```

The HTML (Results.html) Page is:

```
<html>
  <body>
     {% for task_id in tasks %}
        <h3>{{task_id}}</h3>
     {% endfor %}
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed the for loop and rewrote the code as below:

```
@app.route('/')
def Results():
    try:
        Project_List_Col = db.ppm_master_db_collection.find()
        return render_template('Results.html',tasks=Project_List_Col)
    except Exception as e:
        return dumps({'error': str(e)})

if __name__ == '__main__':  
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Documents are displayed on the HTML Page as is.

(***Will work on the formatting part. Meanwhile any pointers are greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `key,value` function of for loop and also remove that **loop** in the python app file from route like upper answer @Dinakar suggested

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).